# What is the relationship between First Formics War Marvel comics and Card/Johnston prequel books?

Tags: enders-game, adaptation-comparison

What is the relationship between First Formics War Marvel comics (*[Formic Wars: Burning Earth](http://www.comixology.com/Formic-Wars-Burning-Earth/comics-series/5517)* and on) and Card/Johnston prequel book trilogy ([*Earth Unaware*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Unaware), *Earth Afire* and *Earth Awakens*)?

From rough descriptions of the comics, they sound like they cover similar or same materials. Are they simply comic tie-in to prequel books? Or just happened to cover similar stories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in *Afterword* to "*Earth Unaware*".

The comics were Card's idea, and the books were an offshot of the comics, covering the same events in more details.

- First, Marvel did adaptations of existing Ender books as comics
- Then, Card gave them idea to create new comics (what would become *Formic Wars* series)
- Then, they wrote the novels, as planned:

  > So Scott and I had to make some concessions and exclude people and events from the comics that we knew would only exist in the novels

In addition, Card was Executive Director and Creative Director of the comics:

[image]

---

***UPDATE***:

Found another canon confirmation that they are the same story, from Card's web site. He posts various reviews (under "*Uncle Orson Reviews Everything*" rubric) on hatrack, and has [this to say about *Earth Unaware* Book](http://www.hatrack.com/osc/reviews/everything/2012-07-19.shtml):

> Aaron Johnston scripted the Formic Wars graphic novel series (Burning Earth; Silent Strike) from Marvel Comics; **now we're creating novel versions of the same story**.

Comment: Sorry - I was going to answer this (actually, comment it in the original question), but hadn't got to it yet.